# OpenAPI design-first API reference

Tags: swagger, swagger-node

I am trying to document a REST API reference using the OpenAPI format (v2).
I want it to be "design-first", meaning that my swagger spec will be the contract of the API implementation.

I have tried many modules and solutions e.g. **swagger-node** (too opiniated about folder structure and implementation), **swaggerize-express** which forces me to use express, etc. I also tried an **generator-openapi-repo** but it seems outdated and no more maintained.

Any solution out there to document a REST API reference, design-first and without coupling the documentation with the actual implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) just as a local editor. With these commands, run the swagger editor and write your swagger specification:

`npm install -g swagger`

`swagger project create my-app`

`swagger project edit`

After finishing the design, `swagger.yaml` file which is stored in `api/swagger/`, can be used for any implementation.

If you're searching for an online editor, checking these tools might be helpful.

- Simple editor: [editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io/)
- Collaborate editor (offering free & paid version): [swaggerhub.com](https://swaggerhub.com/)